# How to Pass array in Volt Template to javascript

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I'm using **Phalcon** and **Volt** template engine  .

This **index.volt** and I'm going to pass an array to JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

 var usersList= {{ array_from_volt }} ;

</javascript>
```

But it doesn't work .

in PHP we used to do like this But it **doesn't** work for **volt**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

 var usersList=  <?php echo json_encode(array_from_php); ?>;

</javascript>
```

So, How can I Pass an Array to javascript from volt ?

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code, use setvar to set a variable that Volt can reference.

```
$this->view->setVar('array_name', $your_array);
```

If you need the array json encoded, you can:

```
$this->view->setVar('array_name', json_encode($your_array));
```

Then in your Volt file, you can set the javascript variable as follows:

```
<script>
    var usersList = [{{ array_name }}];
</script>
```

(note syntax not verified... YMMV)